# Changing custom post type URL issue

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I have this function and it does just what I need, it replace words in URL perfectly, but links don't work. All links are good and display on site well structured, as I wanted, but just don't open posts. Is there any way that I can make it work?

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'replace_link', 1, 3);
function replace_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'item' ){
        return home_url('food/'. $post->ID);
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^food/([^/]*)/?','?item=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: You need corresponding rewrite rules to set the proper query vars for those requests.

Comment: Can you please help me there? I tried but it seams like I cant get right URL structure. I edited my function. @Milo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post_type_link` uses the post's ID, but the `item` query var expects a postname. To query by ID you need to use the `p` query var and set `post_type`:

```
add_rewrite_rule('food/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?post_type=item&p=$matches[1]','top');
```

Comment: Thanks  but still 404. Maybe I should do flush_rewrite somewhere or something similar. @Milo

Comment: After adding or changing rewrites you must flush rules. Visiting the permalinks settings admin page is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing. I'm going to look for different solution.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the rule, edited version above is tested and working.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just one more question, what if I want to use post name insted of post ID in URL? I put in the first function `return home_url('food/'. $post->post_name);`, how should I change add_rewrite_rule? And thank you once more for your respond! @Milo

Comment: you would swap `post_type=item&p=$matches[1]` with `item=$matches[1]`